# On an exercise on double integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \, \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2} \le 1\} \setminus R$, where $R$ is the rectangle with vertices $(\pm \sqrt{2},\pm 1)$.

I need to compute the integral

$$
\iint_D x^2 dxdy
$$

Our domain consists of 4 pieces. Actually, it is sufficient to work with the northest and the eastern pieces, and multiply the two integrals so obtained by $2$. Let $D_1$ the northest piece of our domain. Here, $x \in [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$, while $y$ varies starting from $1$ and following the ellipse. I think I need to use polar coordinates, but I have no clue on how to use them in such a case.

Comment: What if $x=2r\cos(\theta), y=\sqrt{2}r\sin(\theta)$, with $r\in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{2} \leq 1 \}$.

$ \begin{align} 
\iint \limits_{D} x^2 dxdy &= \iint \limits_{S} x^2 dxdy - \iint \limits_{R} x^2dxdy \\ \iint \limits_{S}x^2 dxdy &= \int _{-2}^{2}dx \int_{-\sqrt{2-\frac{x^2}{2}}} ^{\sqrt{2-\frac{x^2}{2}}} x^2 dy \\ &= \int _{-2}^{2}x^2 dx \int_{-\sqrt{2-\frac{x^2}{2}}} ^{\sqrt{2-\frac{x^2}{2}}} dy \\ &= 2 \int _{-2}^{2} x^2 \sqrt{2-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx \\ &= 2\sqrt{2} \int _{- \pi} ^0 (2 \cos \theta)^2 \sqrt{1-\cos ^2 \theta} \  d(2 \cos \theta) , (x =2 \cos \theta) \\ &= 16\sqrt{2} \int _{- \pi} ^0 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta d \theta \\ &= 4\sqrt{2} \int _{- \pi} ^0 \sin^2 2 \theta d \theta \\ &= 2 \sqrt 2 \int _{- \pi} ^0 1-\cos4\theta d \theta \\ &= 2\sqrt {2} \pi \\ \iint \limits_{R} x^2dxdy &= \int _{-\sqrt 2} ^{\sqrt 2} dx \int _{-1} ^{1} x^2 dy \\ &= 2\int _{- \sqrt 2} ^{\sqrt 2} x^2 dx \\ &=\begin{array}{r|l} \frac{2}{3}x^3 & _{- \sqrt 2} ^{\sqrt 2} \end{array} \\ &= \frac{8}{3} \sqrt{2} \end{align}
$

Then, answer is:

$\begin{align} \iint \limits_{D} x^2 dxdy = 2 \sqrt 2 \pi - \frac{8}{3} \sqrt 2 \end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

You can leave it in Cartesian.

$\displaystyle\int_{-2}^{-\sqrt 2} \int_{-\sqrt {2-\frac {x^2}{2}}}^{\sqrt {2-\frac {x^2}{2}}} x^2\ dy\ dx+\int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{1}^{\sqrt {2-\frac {x^2}{4}}} x^2\ dy\ dx+ \int_{-\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt 2} \int_{-\sqrt {2-\frac {x^2}{4}}}^{-1} x^2\ dy\ dx+\int_{\sqrt 2}^2 \int_{-\sqrt {2-\frac {x^2}{2}}}^{\sqrt {2-\frac {x^2}{2}}} x^2\ dy\ dx$

And since the integrand is even and the region symmetric simplify it to just two regions and double them.

A simple change of variables would be $x = \sqrt 2 u$

$\displaystyle 2\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{1}^{\sqrt {2-2u^2}} u^2\sqrt 2\ dy\ du+ 2\int_1^{\sqrt 2} \int_{-\sqrt {2-2u^2}}^{\sqrt {2-2u^2}} u^2\sqrt 2  dy\ du$

And now the conversion to polar is looking more obvious.

$u = r\cos \theta\\
y = r\sin\theta$

$\displaystyle 8\sqrt 2 \int_{0}^{\frac \pi 4}\int_{\sec\theta}^{\sqrt 2} r^2\cos^2\theta \ dr\ d\theta$

None of these look too bad.